# Remove entire data from Oracle XE because it's full

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-xe, impdp

I take the liberty of asking you because I have a problem with Oracle XE. I use the free version which allows me to store 12GB of data.

I receive a dump every week, the imports worked well but the 12GB are exceeded and I cannot launch any more import

I have been trying for 4 hours to find a solution. I looked on the internet to delete all the data and put it back but impossible, I still have the message that I am over 12 GB.

I made a "DROP TABLE matable PURGE;" for each table I import, I performed a "PURGE RECYCLEBIN;" I restarted the script and I still get this error message

[image]

Translation of the image :

Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue March 24 10:45:08 2020

Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and / or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

ORA-39002: invalid operation ORA-31694: Failed to load / unload master table "SYS". "SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_03" ORA-02354: error during the export / import of data

ORA-39776: serious API error of direct path when loading the table "SYS". "SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_03" ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum size of authorized database ( 12 GB)

If you could help me it would be perfect

thank you so much

Comment: You should translate the error messages (you can use the by ORA-ID) so it'll be easier for people to answer

Comment: I've translated the image, it would be better now

Answer (score 0):

If Express Edition database exceeds 12 GB, there's nothing much you can do but purchase licence for e.g. Standard Edition.

Or, you could try to drop the database (entirely), install it back again and then perform import, but that won't help much as you're still at 12 GB limit (or very close to it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we need to only work with Oracle XE, because we will use this process until December 2020 and i don't understand how works Oracle Pricing

Comment: As I said, if you exceeded 12GB, you hit the limit. Oracle is expensive, that's correct. If you can't afford it, switch to e.g. MySQL.

Comment: but i choose certains tables during the import but i want to flush the data to reimport

Comment: That would be the 2nd paragraph I wrote. Just, don't do that if that's the only database you have - install another copy of XE on another computer.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to drop the database entirely but i d'ont how to do that, if you can tell me how to do it will be perferct

Comment: First of all, I'm not a DBA. I think you have to uninstall XE entirely because (once again, I think) that it won't allow you drop the database and create it.

Comment: I've uninstall and reinstall all Oracle XE but it takes me an hour, and i want to automate the process, the is no other solution to purge the database et reuse impdp to import ?